# Run projects on github locally

Tags: angularjs, github, drag-and-drop

I need to check drag and drop feature in angularjs .
Any idea how i  can run the following project locally on my system.:https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Comment: Just clone or download the repository, and then you are ready to test it

Comment: yeah after downloading how can i actually run the code.

Comment: all the details you need are here: README.md, just after you clone/download the repository. Here is the demo inside the repository: http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested

Answer (score 0):

Download the repository & then extract contents of the folder & navigate to the following folder: `angular-drag-and-drop-lists-master/angular-drag-and-drop-lists-master/demo/` and run `index.html` and you are good to go. Same is with cloning repository.

Comment: That was one of the folder that i saw. There were many & you can dive into any folder & run its relevant html file.